# Darken the entire page when opening and produce a fade out effect when closing a dialog window

Tags: javascript, html, css, dialog

I have this html code in my page where I create a dialog tag. When I click on a button, this dialog window opens:

```
<!-- note that the CSS is in another file, it just to show you -->
<style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
  #window {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 380px;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 40px 1px #656565;
  }
</style>

<dialog id="window">
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
          <a>Detail</a>
        </li>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right" id="exit">Close</button>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body page-header">
    <!-- my content here -->
  </div>
</dialog>
<script>
  (function() {
    var dialog = document.getElementById('window');
    document.getElementById('show').onclick = function() {
      dialog.show();
    };
    document.getElementById('exit').onclick = function() {
      dialog.close();
    };
  })();
  $('#window').addClass('animated fadeIn');
</script>
```

I would like to darken all my entire page (except my dialog window) when I click on the button who allows me to display the dialog. And then, when I click on Close, my dialog window closes and my entire page returns to its original state.

Moreover, how can I add a *fade out* effect on my dialog window when I click on "Close"?

See the image to have a visual information my page with the dialog window:
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to create an element with fixed position that covers the entire viewable region of the page. It also must render "behind" the dialog. E.g.:

HTML

`<div id="page-mask"></div>`

CSS

```
#page-mask {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I mocked something here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLrNvb

Comment: Scrolling tends to break this, so I normally add a .faded class to the body whenever the mask is rendered so I can do`body.faded {overflow:hidden}` in addition to above. Also edited to use `background` instead of `color`

Comment: @Javier -- how does scrolling break it? Check out the Codepen -- what's broken?

Comment: you're right, I don't know why in some cases I would see the faded background interrupted when scrolling. Seems good here. My bad!

Comment: Thank you two, your answer allows me to find the solution using your code and adapting it to my project and his structure.

Comment: I have same issue too. That I cannot scroll. Can you tell me concrete solution. thanks

Comment: The only reason you would be unable to scroll with it, is if you left out the `position: fixed;` aspect, or if you put the `#page-mask` div inside of another div. It should be a direct child of the body.

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining your code, you can try solving it by creating a position fixed element that is behind your #window element. I asume you are loading jQuery.

**CSS**

```
#window {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 380px;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 40px 1px #656565;
  z-index: 999;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 998;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="overlay"></div>

<dialog id="window">
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a>Detail</a>
      </li>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right" id="exit">Close</button>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body page-header">
    <!-- my content here -->
  </div>
</dialog>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  var dialog = document.getElementById('window');
  document.getElementById('show').onclick = function() {
    overlay.fadeIn(250);
    dialog.fadeIn(300);
  };
  document.getElementById('exit').onclick = function() {
    overlay.fadeOut(300);
    dialog.fadeOut(250);
  };
})();
```