# Blur background of Popup Window

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you click on `Forgot your password? Press me` a popup window opens. When it opens, I want the background to be blurred. I tried to use `filter: blur(20px);` but that blurs the window itself which I don't want.

```js
let forgotField = document.getElementById('field');
let forgot = document.getElementById('forgot');
    forgot.addEventListener('click', () => {
        forgotField.style.display = 'block';
    });
```

```css
#field {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 80px;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
#content {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 40px;
    color: white;
}

#forgot {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<body id="login-section">
    <section>
        <a id="forgot">Forgot your password? Press me</a>
    </section>
    
    <div id="field">
        <div id="content">
            <p>Here you can set your password back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set the `blur` filter on an element that is a parent of the rest of the page, but not of your popup. Here I added `<div id="blurme">...</div>`, with the main page content inside, as a sibling to the `#field` popup element.

```js
let forgotField = document.getElementById('field');
let forgot = document.getElementById('forgot');
let blurElement = document.getElementById("blurme")

forgot.addEventListener('click', () => {
  forgotField.style.display = 'block';
  blurElement.style.filter = "blur(5px)"
});
```

```css
#field {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

#content {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 40px;
  color: white;
}

#forgot {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="blurme">
    <section>
      <a id="forgot">Forgot your password? Press me</a>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div id="field">
    <div id="content">
      <p>Here you can set your password back</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah works for me Thanks ! But now I have to deal with white borders around my website... Do you know how I can do the whole page a little darker instead of using blur?

Comment: If you want to darken instead of blur, you can create an overlay element that covers the screen with an absolute position and is normally hidden, with a dark and semi-transparent background color like `#000000af`. Make sure to set z-indexes to something appropriate, and then show and hide the overlay to darken the background.

Comment: Much love thank you! <3

Comment: You can check out [Darken the entire page when opening and produce a fade out effect when closing a dialog window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054353/darken-the-entire-page-when-opening-and-produce-a-fade-out-effect-when-closing-a) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

A more modern way would be to use [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element and put a blur on its `::backdrop` pseudo element

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
const forgot = document.getElementById('forgot');

forgot.addEventListener('click', () => {
  dialog.showModal()
});
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 40px;
  color: white;
}

#forgot {
  color: black;
}

#dialog {
  padding: 0;
  &::backdrop {
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog">
  <div id="field">
    <div id="content">
      <p>Here you can set your password back</p>
      <form method="dialog">
        <button autofocus>Close</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</dialog>

<section>
  <a id="forgot">Forgot your password? Press me</a>
</section>
```